# Counting up and then back down in a for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
Function oddNumbers(){
Var odds ="";
For(index=0; index <=10; index ++){
If(index%2 !=0){odds+=index +"."}
}
}

OddNumbers();
```

Trying to count all odd counting numbers up then back down again in a for loop. I can get it to go up with the code again. But when I try nested for I cannot get it to go back down again in the same loop.
How would I get it to loop up then back down?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use only one `loop` definition, you have to define custom [`conditionExpression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) and [`incrementExpression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Here is a quick example.

```js
var direction = 1;

//REM: What gets added on each iteration?
function incrementExpression(){
  //REM: Increase or decrease depending on direction
    return 1*direction
}

//REM: What gets evaluated on each iteration?
function conditionExpression(i){
    if(i < 10 && direction === 1){
        return true
    }
    if(i === 10 && direction === 1){
        direction = -1
        return true
    }
    if(i >= 0 && direction === -1){
        direction = -1
        return true
    };

    //REM: Returns false if direction downwards and i lower zero
    return false
}

for(var i=0; conditionExpression(i); i+=incrementExpression(i)){
    console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: got it to work and filter items to odd, but it doesnt want to move to my div in line                           'code' for (var i = 0; conditionExpression(i); i += incrementExpression(i)) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        document.getElementById("div4").appendChild = i;
        console.log(i + "")
    }

}

Comment: `.appendChild()` adds a node and not a number. Try `.textContent += i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse your for loop on your use-case. See code snippet below:

```js
function oddNumbers() {
var odds = "";
  
  for(index=0; index <=10; index ++){
    if(index%2 !=0) {
      odds+=index +"."
      console.log(odds);
    }
  }
  
  for(index = 10; index > 0; index--) {
    if(index % 2 != 0) {
    odds+=index +"."
        console.log(odds);
    }
  }
}

oddNumbers();
```

Im not sure if that's what you want but that's what I understand on your given code on your question.

Comment: Tried that one and it does express what I need. But I only want to use one "For"